# How to handle dynamic templates and components in Angular

Tags: angular

I am looking to implement the idea of a white label application for different brands in Angular 4/5/6. Based on the brand URL, the angular app should load its custom layout and views. Any idea on how to get started will be much appreciated.

E.g

```
 Brand A
    |---- Load custom templates for brand A and it's views

 Brand B
    |---- Load custom template for brand B and it's views
```

Comment: Learn about angular routing. https://angular.io/docs

Comment: I understand the use of routing, but what I don't want to end up with loads of routes rather I want to dynamically build the page based on the brand. In order words, I want to dynamically build the entire page with it's layout and styling and different layout and styling for another brand

Comment: You can try multiple application under same code base idea, please check this article (https://www.henriksommerfeld.se/code-sharing-with-multi-app-angular-project-using-base-components/), check this for multiple brands: https://github.com/henriksommerfeld/hero-multi-app/blob/master/.angular-cli.json

Comment: Or maybe you can check out the dynamic component section of the angular docs. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader